# Changing from hh:mm:ss and h:m to number of minutes

Tags: pandas, nan, timedelta

I'm working on a health data base for a ML model
I have a DataFrame with an object type columns with heterogeneous data (1600rows) :

```
46        1:37
47        3:50
48        1:09
49        1:30
50        2:08
51         NaN
52        2:36
53        1:32
54    01:23:00
55        0:59
56        1:40
57    02:10:00
58        2:51
59        1:55
Name: delay, dtype: object
```

The format is either hh:mm:ss or h:m I believe and I have trouble converting it to the numbers minutes (while keeping the missing values)
If i use
`pd.to_timedelta(df[delay].astype(str), errors='coerce') / pd.Timedelta(1, 'min')` I get the value i need (number of minutes) for hh:mm:ss rows but I get NaN with h:m values

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use totalseconds function and get the seconds then devide it by 60 to get minutes:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df[delay].astype(str), errors='coerce').totalseconds()/60
```